# Route [method] not defined

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I am creating a form to insert data into database.version *laravel5.1* but my code is not working.
`resources\views\login.blade.php`

```
<!-- Registration Form -->
<form action="{{ URL::route('postform_registration') }}" role="form" id="login_popup_form" method="post" name="login_popup_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <img id="close" src="{{ URL::asset('tradextek/img/close_irtiza.png') }}" alt="" onclick ="div_hide()">
    <h2>Registration</h2>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Your Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_popup_email" name="login_popup_email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Your Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"id="login_popup_password" name="login_popup_password" placeholder="Password...">
    </div>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" onclick="check_empty()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<h3>
    <?php
    if(Session::has('key')){
        echo Session::get('key');
    }
    ?>
</h3>
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('/login',array(
    'as' => 'postform',
    'uses' => 'all_control@postform'
));

Route::post('/login',array(
    'url' => 'postform_registration',
    'uses' => 'all_control@postform_registration'
));
```

app/controllers/all_control

```
public function postform_registration(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->login_popup_email;
    $password = $request->login_popup_password;
    return redirect('login')->with('key', 'You have inserted successfully');
}
```

Error message

```
1)ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 296:
Route [postform] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\login.blade.php)

2)InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 296:
Route [postform] not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

By seeing this code, i guess that,there are two possibilities for your error.

1. in routes.php you have defined:

   ```
   Route::post('/login',array(
   'as' => 'postform',
   'uses' => 'all_control@postform'
   ));
   Route::post('/login',array(
   'url' => 'postform_registration',
   'uses' => 'all_control@postform_registration'
   ));
   ```

   I can't understand why you have different routes entry for same url and same `HTTP` method in your case `POST`.

and you have defined **POST** method for  **routes**

`Route::post('/login',array(
        'as' => 'postform',
        'uses' => 'all_control@postform'
    ));`

and other side you are passing **GET** Reqest from **controller**.

and second points:
Have you defined `postform` in `all_control.php`?

Comment: Route::post('/login',array(
'as' => 'postform',
'uses' => 'all_control@postform'
));  this is for first form in my project and the second one is with error. i want to catch email,password by postform_registration method

Comment: `Route::post('/login',array( 'as' => 'postform', 'uses' => 'all_control@postform' ));` if this is for displaying login form then you have to `get` method instead of `post` method in your route.